# Retrieving Full Name of Stock Exchanges

Tags: curated-data

Asking for a list of stock exchanges by

```
FinancialData["Exchanges"]
```

I get the list posted below comprising letter codes. How do I get the full names related to the codes, a list which says 
AX=Australan Stock Exchange, F=Frankfurt, etc.

> {"AMEX", "AS", "AX", "BATS", "BE", "BG", "BH", "BK", "BO", "BR", \
>   "BW", "CHIX", "CL", "CNSX", "CO", "CR", "CY", "DE", "DH", "DIFX", \
>   "DSMD", "DU", "EE", "F", "FI", "FNFI", "FNSE", "FU", "GH", "GR", \
>   "GT", "HA", "HK", "HM", "HSTC", "HU", "IDX", "IE", "IR", "IS", \
>   "ISEC", "JO", "KA", "KE", "KL", "KS", "KW", "L", "LJ", "LK", "LT", \
>   "LU", "LV", "MA", "MB", "MI", "MK", "MO", "MT", "MU", "MX", "NASDAQ", \
>   "NI", "NS", "NY", "NYSE", "NZ", "OB", "OL", "OM", "PA", "PE", "PG", \
>   "PH", "PK", "PS", "PT", "RO", "RTSX", "RUS", "SA", "SG", "SI", "SS", \
>   "ST", "STC", "SW", "SZ", "TA", "TO", "TR", "TSE", "TW", "UKEX", "V", \
>   "VI", "WA", "XBEL", "XBLB", "XBRA", "XBRV", "XFND", "XGUA", "XJAM", \
>   "XKAZ", "XLIF", "XMAU", "XMCE", "XNEP", "XOAS", "XPTY", "XTNX", \
>   "XTUN", "XVTX", "ZA", "ZB", "ZW"}

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes this can be done in such a way:

```
FinancialData["AMEX", "Name"]
```

> "NYSE American"

Sometimes this doesn't work, e.g.

```
FinancialData["AS", "Name"]
```

> FinancialData::notent: AS is not a known entity, class, or tag for FinancialData. Use FinancialData[] for a list of entities.

A possible explanation from the help is "Certain properties are available only when the relevant market is open:".

Comment: Thanks a lot! Regards - Opal